# Intelligent Ajax Deep Linking for search engines so that Meta data is loaded in HTML instead of DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, google-search

I'm searching for a good way of **deep linking** together with different **meta tags**. Currently I have a huge main HTML site and showing the subpages via JavaScript and DOM manipulations.

Let's take my latest project as example ([**Google Search**](https://www.google.de/search?q=site:arda-maps.org%20-arda-maps.org%2FForum&ei=ZfpdVbfiA4elsAHT3IHAAQ#q=site:arda-maps.org)). There you can see that the meta tags (let's take just the description for simplification) are always the same. But in the DOM I changed it as you can see on the site. But I know Search Engine just take the HTML code and having JS mostly disabled. Here the lines in the JavaScript code that I used to change title, description and keywords.

### Example

```
    $('meta[name=keywords]').attr('content', 'ages,third');
    $('meta[name=description]').attr('content', 'The Third age is where The Hobbit and Lord of the Rings take part.');
    document.title = "Third Age - Arda Maps";
```

As you can see from the Google search, the **title is properly changed**, even tho it is done via JavaScript.

So the question is, if there is a way to also **change** other meta **tags** like the description via JavaScript in a proper way?

*Note #1*: I don't want to use PHP. I know PHP would make it way easier via templating.

*Note #2*: I also know I could just load the different pages via Ajax. But then I would have to mirror them. And as you can see the main html is very big. Mirroring would in this way be contra-productive. Isn't it?

Comment: note that *"But I know Search Engine just take the HTML code and having JS mostly disabled."* isn't so true anymore with google indexing.

Comment: That's why I say *mostly* because I know about that fact indeed. But I also know that Search Engine don't like JavaScript in General. =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is **no way to edit the meta tags** on a Single-Page web application easily for different pages. The only way is via PHP or Node.js to change it on server-side.

Chaning it on client-side it will just change the DOM what is good for the user as he can see the changes. But search engine will ignore that. Also with the Dublin Core it will not work. Even tho it is designed for just this.

So currently this is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

> So the question is, if there is a way to also change other meta tags
>   like the description via JavaScript in a proper way?

See [Making AJAX Applications Crawlable](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/)

---

> open for anything except PHP solutions.

See [DCMI Metadata Terms](http://dublincore.org/documents/dcmi-terms) , [Expressing Dublin Core metadata using HTML/XHTML meta and link elements](http://dublincore.org/documents/dc-html/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
  <head profile="http://dublincore.org/documents/2008/08/04/dc-html/">
    <title>title</title>
    <link rel="schema.DC" href="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" />
    <meta name="DC.subject" content="subject1, subject2" />
    <meta name="DC.title" content="title" />
    <meta name="DC.description" content="description" />
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well that does not really help because it just describes the hash key. But my question was about real subpages and not just hash keys. And that makes it more difficult I think. isn't it? Anyway thanks for the link.

Comment: @kwoxer Read , tried link at  "Full Specification" -> "Role of the Search Engine Crawler" -> "Transformation of URL" -> "4." ?

Comment: I read but I did not understand how this could help me out. I mean this one is saying how to change the fragment. But I don't have issues with the fragment. And in my case I don't use a fragment here. So I have no clue how this could help me. Could you maybe write something about this. That would be great.

Comment: @kwoxer What is expected result of changing `meta` elements with `js` ?

Comment: Well I want to use it for deep linking. And currently it is just changing the DOM as you can see from the example. So basically I just need something like *document.description = "new descr..."* like I already do with the title and all would be fine =)

Comment: Try utilizing `dc.terms` http://dublincore.org/documents/dcmi-terms/  `meta` tag "descriptions" in addition to standard `meta` tags . These should be "indexed" along with standard `meta` tags. Not exactly certain what expected result is ? , why `js` would be used to accomplish this ? The results could be viewed at "rich snippets testing tool" .

Comment: Well in which way would you solve my issue? I mean I'm open for anything except PHP solutions. =)

Comment: Thank you. I added some example code. Could you have a look if that looks fine. If yes I'll wait until Google is updating the SERP and then tag your answer as working =) Anyway looks like a good way, hopefully also adapted in this way by all the different Engines.

Comment: Now over some days tested. It does not seem to work. Still all the old entrys in Google search somehow.

Comment: @kwoxer Can describe _" It does not seem to work."_ ? See at OP __ "So the question is, if there is a way to also change other meta tags like the description" ? _"Still all the old entrys in  search somehow."_  Are updated `meta` tags being parsed at "testing tool" ?

Comment: Mhh it's very hard to say if something works or not, that's clear. There are many factors for sure. I mean overall is my snippet here correct? Or is there anything huge missing. I also had a closer look again here: http://dublincore.org/documents/dc-html/ and could not find a big mistake, I might have done. So it's now up to Google to index it correctly? I also forwarded all www links to the non-www version via 301, but still no change in the Google serp... it seems really that the page first of all needs to be more attractive before further testings somehow =/

Comment: @kwoxer Does `html` at answer resolve question at OP _"the question is, if there is a way to also change other meta tags like the description via JavaScript in a proper way?"_ ?

Comment: It does not matter in which language I change something to get it working. In HTML with the DC is a great way. But that for now does not work. Javascript would also be fine but will difinitily not work because Search Engine ignore JS. Did I get your message wrong? What is OP?

Comment: @kwoxer "OP" is original post / original poster . Does solution at Answer resolve Question as to how to add `meta` tags to document ? Are `meta` tags described at solution above parsed and viewable at "structured data testing tool" ?

Comment: Found out that Google does not support the DC. So thats the reason for no changes... https://scholar.google.dk/intl/en/scholar/inclusion.html#indexing