# Alternative to Ajax content loading for a One Page Website for proper meta tags

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-search

I meanwhile spent over two months to observe the SERP of my website [**Arda Maps**](http://arda-maps.org/). It is still the fact that [Google](https://www.google.de/?gws_rd=ssl#q=site:arda-maps.org) does not list all of the subpages and the incorrect meta tags.

I got a [tip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30378184/intelligent-ajax-deep-linking-for-search-engines-so-that-meta-data-is-loaded-in) to use the **Dublin Core**. But [Google](https://scholar.google.dk/intl/en/scholar/inclusion.html#indexing) themself say "as a last resort". For me this means that they do not completely ignore the DC, do they? But yeah DC does not work for me.

I searched a lot but I not even found a single **One Page Website** with linked subpages which have different meta tags in the SERP. And if there are some these are usual PHP scripts or they load content via Ajax.

So my question is, is there anything out there that makes it possible to get indexed in a proper way without using Ajax. I mean loading subpages via Ajax is fine... but there you have to mirror so much in this case. So do you know any alternative to Ajax for loading proper meta tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched a lot around, but it does not seem that there is a working solution without PHP or Node.js. That's really bad but as Single-Page are not frequently used in the web, I think that's ok. So Single-Pages have some huge disadvatanges in that term.